# Estimating a probability distribution, determine quality of estimate from one sample

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have an infinite set of unknown discrete probability distributions, all on the same support. I also have a method of estimating each distribution, but I don't know if my estimates are accurate.

I can obtain a maximum of one sample drawn from each distribution. I want to know if my estimation method is accurate. How can I determine this?

I know that question is a bit fuzzy, here's a sharper version. If my estimates were all perfectly accurate, could I confirm this fact, and if so how?

I'm sure this problem has been studied as there are countless applications (e.g. election forecasting), I just don't know the language to search for.

Comment: If you have only one estimate $x_i$ from each sample, then it is clear that your point estimate for the mean is $x_i$ and for the variance $0$. In other words, a degenerate random variable that takes value $x_i$ with probability $1$. Needless to say this tells us nothing about the actual distribution of $X_i$ So I don't really think what you are proposing works very well.

Comment: You have an infinite set of distributions, but each distribution is itself unknown?  What do you mean by "estimating each distribution"?  And does estimating a distribution in any way affect estimating _another_ distribution in the same infinite set?

Comment: @antkam The distributions aren't completely unknown, I know something about each of them which doesn't require sampling from them. I have a (possibly noisy) side channel giving me this information. Based on past observations (a single sample from each distribution), I want to determine if the side channel is reliable.